# C++ program doesn't fully execute iteration

Tags: c++

The program I've written is supposed to take in two user inputs (one being the number we're meant to check whether it's k-hyperperfect or not, the other being a maximum k-value.) if the input integer is k-hyperperfect in the range of 1 to the inputted maximum k-value, then the output should be that k-value. For example, if the input integer is 21 and the maximum k-value is 100 then the output should be 2.

My program gives the correct output for (the first number is the input integer, the second number is the k-max value, the third number is output value) ...

- 21 (input integer) 100 (k-max) --> 180
- 301 100 --> 6
- 12211188308281 100 --> 0
- -301 100 --> 0
- 21 -5 --> 0

However, it doesn't correctly execute for 12211188308281 and 200 (it gives me 0 when it should give me 180). I've run my code through a step by step visualizer and it seems to just abruptly stop execution when i = 496 in the for loop within the else statement. But I don't understand why since it executes correctly for 5 other test runs.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl; using std::fixed;


int main () { 
    int number; 
    int kmax; 
    int sum = 0 ; 
    int hyper = 0; 

    std::cin >> number; 
    std::cin >> kmax; 

    if (number <= 6 or kmax < 1) {
        std::cout << "0" << "\n"; 
    } 
    else { 
        for (int i=1;i<=number;i++) { 
            if (number%i==0 and i != 1 and i != number){ 
                    sum+= i; 
                }
            }
        }

    for (int k=1; k <= kmax; k++) { 
        hyper = ((sum)*k) + 1;
        if (hyper == number) { 
            std::cout << k << endl; 
            break; 
        } 
        } 

}
```

Comment: "_I've ran my code through a step by step visualizer and it seems to just abruptly stop execution when i = 496_" Did you look at the values of the local variables, at this stage, to give you a hint, of why does it "stop abruptly"?

Comment: Just a note - your `else { continue;}` block does absolutely nothing. Get rid of it

Comment: Well, `12211188308281` won't fit in an `int`, for one thing. Try `long long`.

Comment: `12211188308281` might be too big to fit in `int`, depending on computer architecture. Try `long long`

Comment: Did you check the value of `number`? `12211188308281` is much larger than you can fit inside a 32-bit integer.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to include `cmath` or `iomanip`, as you are not using anything from these includes.

Comment: Please note that performing `number % i` 12211188308281 times to calculate the sum of all the divisors of `number` it's unlikely to be the supposed way to solve this problem. It would take quite a long time, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that numbers read through `std::istream`s (like `std::cin`) are read successfully. As the value that you enter for number is too large to store in an integer your read will fail. For example you could change your code to:

```
int main()
{
    int number;     
    std::cin >> number; 
    if ( !std::cin )
    {
        std::cout << "invalid value: " << number << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "valid value: " << number << "\n";        
    }
    // calculate answer
    return 0;
}
```

You would then see your program printing `"invalid value: 2147483647"` if you have a c++11 compliant compiler or an undefined number if you have an older compiler.

Now that you have implemented reading values correctly the fix to your issue is to use a larger integer type like `int64_t` which is able to hold your number.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the `int` type in your machine isn't big enough to store the value 12,211,188,308,281.

The C++ standard only mandates it to be capable of storing a value up to 32,767 and even in the (now common) case of a 32-bit `int` or `long int`), the limit would be 2,147,483,647. So you need a `long long int` or an `int64_t` (if it's present in your implementation).

A simple check like

```
if (std::cin >> number >> kmax ) { // perform calculations...
```

Would have shown the error sooner.

That beeing said, there are also some simple changes that could be done to the posted code in order to make it more efficient. The first loop can be optimized considering the "symmetry" of the divisors of a given number: meaning, if n is divisible by a, so that b = n/a is a whole number, b too is a divisor of n. This will limit the number of iterations to the square root of n, instead of n.

```
long long int number, 
              kmax, 
              sum = 0; 

 // ...

long long int temp = number,
              i = 2;
for (; i * i < number; i++) { 
    if (number % i == 0) {
        temp = number / i;
        sum += i + temp; 
    }
}
if (i * i == number) {
    sum += i;
}
```

There probably are better algorithms, but I'm unfamiliar with those.

The second loop, in my opinion, is unnecessary. The value k can be calculated directly:

```
if ( (number - 1) % sum == 0) {
    std::cout << (number - 1) / sum << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a too long value 12211188308281 to integer "number", which can't contain it fully and it is getting truncated to 596285753. You can add a print statement to print it.

```
std::cout<<number;
```

which will print 596285753. 
As suggested you should use long long int. Again its dependent on the software platform running on your system.

Comment: "_which can't contain it fully and it is getting truncated to 596285753_" Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes, I assigned the provided value to integer variable and found that it got truncated to this value all the time. Please tried it, but agree it can be different for different compiler.

Comment: I don't doubt that you got such value, by running the code on your machine. I just stated, that the C++ standard does not define the behavior, of the program, which contains signed integer overflow.

Comment: actually `sdt::cin` should fail and the value of number should be set to std::numeric_limits<T>::max() (after c++11) or the value will be undefined (before c++11).